# Rename filenames inside a RAR before extraction?

Tags: macos, rename, rar

I have several files inside a RAR that have the same filename.

So Im thinking I should either:

Rename them inside the RAR before I extract them

OR

Extract each file into a separate folder (so they dont overwrite each other) and rename the filenames later

OR

Make sure that whatever tool I use will not overwrite any files and automatically rename them.

Can anyone recommend a tool and/or process to get all the files without overwriting ?

Im on a Mac BUT Im perfectly comfortable with the command-line (I use Homebrew for my packages).

Answer (score 2):

Just like WinRAR, [RAR for OS X](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) supports the `-or` switch:

```
-or     Rename extracted files automatically if file with the same name already
        exists. Renamed file will get the name like 'filename(N).txt', where
        'filename.txt' is the original file name and 'N' is a number starting
        from 1 and incrementing if file exists.
```